# Collecting first three characters from each line down - Strings C++

Tags: c++, string

I have a string which looks like this

```
".V/1LBOG^"
        ".F/AV0094/08NOV/SAL/Y^"
        ".N/0134249356001^"
        ".S/Y/17K/C/064/064^"
        ".W/K/1/13^"
        ".P/TELLEZBAQUERO/XIMENABKB^"
        ".L/YAT9AP^"
```

what i need to do is remove the first three letters of each line and puch back into a vector i thought of using the substr method but it did not seem to work properly. So i wondering if there is any other possible way from using the substr method.

i.e so in the vector id need to have

```
0[.F/] 1[.N/] 2[.S/]
```

and so on...
any im gratefull for any help.

At the moment im am using a parser

```
 bool ok = qi::parse(first, last, (
          qi::raw [ '.' > qi::char_("EV") > '/' ]
        > qi::raw [ *(qi::char_ - qi::eol) ]
    ) % qi::eol,
    mappings);
```

This will collect each line as required but you have to type in the Letter i.e V or E etc i would need to to go through the string and get each letter regardless.

Comment: correction 0[.V/] and so on...

Comment: post your code which is going wrong, may be a small tweak would get it to work..

Comment: at the moment it is a parser

at the moment its a parser   bool ok = qi::parse(first, last, (
              qi::raw [ '.' > qi::char_("EV") > '/' ]
            > qi::raw [ *(qi::char_ - qi::eol) ]
        ) % qi::eol,
        mappings);

This will collect each line as required but you have to type in the Letter i.e V or E etc i would need to to go through the string and get each letter regardless. @Nim

Comment: @ShamariCampbell please edit your question instead of posting code in the comments.

Comment: Been done @LuchianGrigore above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, if you have a `std::vector<std::string>` this would look like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < myvec.size(); ++i)
{
    myvec[i] = myvec[i].substr(3);
}
```

> i thought of using the substr method but it did not seem to work properly.

Always write why it *did not work properly*. Of course it does, you just did not use it properly. When in question look up the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/).

Comment: So this is retrieving the first three letters off each cell i imagine? @Constantinius

Comment: No, this is making a substring from the fourth character to the end. Please read the documentation of `substr`, I posted a link.

Comment: ah yes would be 0,3 for that, cheers man thanks for your help i shall try that out

Comment: If I understand the SO right, he want the three _first_ character in each string. @ShamariCampbell To get the three first use `str.substr(0, 3)`

Comment: Yeah that is correct so that method above should retrieve each (0,3) from each cell ?

Comment: Shamari Campbell: If you want the first 3 characters of your input strings use `substr(0, 3)`, if you want all but the first 3 use `substr(3)`

Comment: ah i see the problem with code above i need the first three **characters (0,3)** of the string after each **'^'** character as you can see the **'^'** separates the string in a sense